# How do I use ADO to connect a database?

Tags: ado

I'm not trying to run a command with ADO, I am trying to display data, I am being forced to use it at work even though I know I can use connection strings for more simple connections.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADO.net is very simple to use. To display data you just need a connection, a command and a datatable to hold the result set. Then you can use the datatable as a DataSource.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Using dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From YourTable;", cn)
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I already figured it out but I hope this is useful for other people.